# Unable to deploy UiPath NuGet Package using Azure DevOps Extension (UiPath.CLI / uipcli.exe)

Tags: azure-devops, uipath, uipath-orchestrator

Unable to deploy packages to different environments in same orchestrator in uipath using azure devops.

while deploying uipath deploy task we are getting the following error.

System.InvalidOperationException: Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'
##[error]Error deploying package: Error: The process 'C:\Users\chepp\Documents\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.195.1_work_tool\uipcli\1.0.8004-24226\x64\uipcli.exe' failed with exit code 1.

Also attached my log folder here. we are having 3 different environments but unable to deploy in all the 3 environments.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. In its current form, your question is not a great fit for SO. Please provide some (relevant) information on what you tried and how that didn't work. Also, refer to [ask]. On-topic: You get a **Conflict**, could be (that version of) the package already exists.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the UiPath.CLI (uipcli.exe) is unsupported, however you could probably check Vendor support for the Azure DevOps Extension which depends on the UiPath.CLI.

> 'Conflict' ##[error]Error deploying package

I'm also making an assumption that your use of "Environments" is referring to the Environment Entity required for Classic Folders in Orchestrator and that you are using a single Tenant Package Feed.

This implies to me that the Package Version you are attempting to deploy already exists. Double check the package that is packed has been incremented and/or remove the existing deployed package version if it exists.